# How to exclude double counts when calculating similarity of documents in quanteda

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, quanteda

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity between 160 documents (`dfm_daten`) and then exporting them as a pair-wise list into Excel.

Code:

```r
cosdocpair <- textstat_simil(dfm_daten, method = "cosine", margin = "documents")
listcosdoc <- as.data.frame(cosdocpair, sorted = TRUE, diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
```

I understand that `upper = FALSE` should eliminate the double counts `(A,B)` and `(B,A)`, which I want to exclude, but the list that I produce always contains both `(A,B)` and `(B,A)`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**
Thank you, Ken. This is strange. It works with your example but when I use my DFM, it does not work for some reason. Here is my code again:

```
cosdocpair <- textstat_simil(dfm_daten, method = "cosine", margin = "documents")
liste <- as.data.frame(cosdocpair, sorted = TRUE, diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
liste[order(liste$cosine),]
```

and then the first few lines of output are as follows:

```
                  document1               document2     cosine
10792      8_mck_NY_8_yes.pdf  161_acn_2016_67_no.pdf 0.03571487
22169  161_acn_2016_67_no.pdf      8_mck_NY_8_yes.pdf 0.03571487
10787   75_dlt_2016_12_no.pdf  161_acn_2016_67_no.pdf 0.03879965
21374  161_acn_2016_67_no.pdf   75_dlt_2016_12_no.pdf 0.03879965
934        8_mck_NY_8_yes.pdf  103_acn_2018_9_yes.pdf 0.03975923
22107  103_acn_2018_9_yes.pdf      8_mck_NY_8_yes.pdf 0.03975923
```

which shows that the double counts are still in.

Answer (score 1):

With those settings of the conversion to data.frame, you will not have A,B and B,A pairs, just A,B.

Demonstration:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

dfm_daten <- dfm(c(
  A = "a a b c c d",
  B = "a d d b c",
  C = "a a a c c"
))

cosdocpair <- textstat_simil(dfm_daten, method = "cosine", margin = "documents")
as.data.frame(cosdocpair, sorted = TRUE, diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
##   document1 document2    cosine
## 1         A         B 0.8366600
## 2         A         C 0.8770580
## 3         B         C 0.5241424
```